# How does NPM resolve & run scripts from package-json?

Tags: node.js, npm

For curiosity's sake, I want to create a folder in node_modules and be able to run it as a script in package.json's "scripts", but I have not been able to find out how to.

I've noticed with other package.json scripts like "react-scripts" that they wont work in the command line, but will when NPM runs them. How does npm resolve scripts?

Does it have to be a legit package for NPM to run it? (Like, will it check against the NPM registry for if that package exists, or contains scripts?)

Comment: Did you read https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script?

Comment: Just did. Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a module has a `["bin"` entry in its `package.json`][1](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin), then `npm` will put the executable script specified by that `"bin"` entry into a `.bin` folder in `node_modules`.

[When running a script with `npm run`, `npm` will put that `node_modules/.bin` directory first in the `PATH`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script#description) so they are found with `npm run` but not when run directly from the shell.